# Pig CLI getting stuck with ">>" symbol prompting for input

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'd like to understand what is wrong with below Pig code. The last time of below code cause Pig CLI getting stuck with ">>" prompting for input but regardless of what I enter, it continued to prompt.

```
 newServiceIdMapping  = load '/idn/home/data/new/ServiceIdMapping_test.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (market : chararray , serviceId : chararray , rm : chararray , serviceChannel : chararray , team : chararray , pm : chararray , tl : chararray , gh : chararray );

 newServiceIdMappingUpd = FOREACH newServiceIdMapping GENERATE (serviceId,rm , (pm == '' ? tl : pm) As pm1  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the brackets after GENERATE.

```
newServiceIdMapping  = load '/idn/home/data/new/ServiceIdMapping_test.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (market : chararray , serviceId : chararray , rm : chararray , serviceChannel : chararray , team : chararray , pm : chararray , tl : chararray , gh : chararray );

newServiceIdMappingUpd = FOREACH newServiceIdMapping GENERATE serviceId,rm , (pm == '' ? tl : pm) as pm1 ;
```